# TFS 2018 build - svn connection not working for "Get Sources" step

Tags: svn, tfs, tfsbuild

We have a TFS 2018 setup with a build agent configured. The build should be pulling sources from svn. We have a "Service Connection" configured in TFS to talk to svn. This requires the "svn" capability in the build pipeline. We manually added the needed files for svn pulls [svn.exe and the associated dll's] and add the Key-Value in the agent capabilities. TFS build still complains with the error

> [section]Starting: Get Sources
>
> Can't find installed svn command line utility

I can confirm that the "svn.exe" exists in the "path" specified path in the "capabilities" and it works. [we tested it fro the command line "svn info ]". We also restarted the build agent multiple times

TFS app tier and build agent are on different boxes.
Interestingly, we have another TFS instance where the TFS app tier and the build agent are on the same box, svn connection and builds work perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. We also need to the add the path to the "exe" to the system PATH and restart build agents

Comment: You can avoid rebooting the machine by restarting the agent service.